# Using mutual recursion to do a binary comparison of two files; would prefer to use one method, calling itself. How?

Tags: java, recursion

I've made a crossword (and similar) puzzle helper, which enables searching a dictionary for matches to a pattern such as **pa??ern**, **pa***, **pa??ern***, etc., where ? and * have the same meaning as wildcards in Windows (? matches any letter; * matches any number of letters [including 0]).

I found two text dictionaries online, one with 108,000+ words, the other with 80,000+. I assumed that the smaller would be a subset of the larger. Not even close.

So I wrote a Java program to compare and to print any word that is in one dictionary but not in the other. (Turned out there were 24,000+ words in the smaller than in the larger; 52,000+ in larger but not in smaller. So I now, via another program, have a dictionary with 132,000+ words.)

I used ***mutual recursion*** to accomplish this:

```
-When current words match, continue; nothing to print here. 
-When current word from dictionary A is "<" than current word in B, then...
     * print and read A until finding word ">=" current word in B.
       --If '=', they match; continue without printing.
       --If '>', then reverse the process: 
       * print and read B until finding word ">=" current word in A.
...
```

This is all there is to the logic. I really like recursion because it's how we think, though it's often very hard to get those thoughts into code.

And some things about the nature of programmatic recursion are very hard.

In particular, I had to use "dual" methods: one for reading A until >= B; one for reading B until >= A.

I tried to make one routine that would call itself in the same way the different routines call each other, as described above in pseudocode.

**I'm asking for someone to show me how to use ONE method to call itself to accomplish the goal.**

Here's the code that works but is inefficient, as described:

```
package filecomparison;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShorterBinaryCompare {
  static int      kta = 0, exa = 0,     ktb = 0, exb = 0;
  static Scanner  sca,                  scb;
  static String   reca,                 recb;
  static Path a = Paths.get("C:\\newdic.txt");
  static Path b = Paths.get("C:\\WordHelp.dick");

  private static int read_a_untilGE_b(){
    while(sca.hasNext()){
      if(reca.equals(recb))        return 0; // 0 => a = b
      if(reca.compareTo(recb) > 0) break;         // a > b
      System.out.println(reca); exa++; kta++;
      reca = sca.next();
    }
    read_b_untilGE_a();
    return 0;
  }

  private static int read_b_untilGE_a(){
    while(scb.hasNext()){
      if(recb.equals(reca))        return 0;  // a = b
      if(recb.compareTo(reca) > 0) break;     // b > a
      System.out.println("\t\t" + recb); exb++; ktb++;
      recb = scb.next(); 
    } 
    read_a_untilGE_b();
    return 0;
  }

  private static void drain(String msg, Scanner sc){
    int k = 0;
    System.out.println("\n\nDraining " + msg);
    String s;
      while(sc.hasNext()){
        s = sc.next();
        System.out.println(s);
        ++k;
      }
      System.out.println("\nExtras at end: " + k);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Compare:\n" + a + " vs. \n" + b + "\n");

    sca = new Scanner(a);   scb = new Scanner(b);    

    while(sca.hasNext() && scb.hasNext()){

        reca = sca.next(); kta++;
        recb = scb.next(); ktb++;

        int compareResult = reca.compareTo(recb);

        if(     compareResult < 0) read_a_untilGE_b();   // a < b
        else if(compareResult > 0) read_b_untilGE_a() ;  // a > b
                   // mutually-recursive read...untils make a = b at this point        
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nRecords in " + a.toString() + ": " + kta);
    System.out.println("Extras in " + a.toString() + ": " + exa);
    System.out.println("Records in " + b.toString() + ": " + ktb);
    System.out.println("Extras in " + b.toString() + ": " + exb);
    if(sca.hasNext()){ drain(a.toFile().toString(), sca); }    
    if(scb.hasNext()){ drain(b.toFile().toString(), scb); }
  } 
}
```

Here's the last version I tried of one method calling itself. It worked as long as it was the "left" file with the extra words, but when it changed so that the "right" file had the extras, it didn't take long to get stack overflow. Maybe I'm closer than I thought; but I'm out of gas for the day.

**Can you modify the method below, which calls itself, to do what mutual recursion does in the code above?**

```
  private static int read_untilGE_(Scanner a, Scanner b){
    String sa, sb;
    if(b.hasNext())
      sb = b.next();
    else
      return -1;
    System.out.println("Extra in " + a.toString()); 
    while(sca.hasNext()){
      sa = sca.next();
      if(sa.equals(sb))        return 0;  // a = b
      if(sa.compareTo(sb) > 0) break;     // a > b
      System.out.println(sa); exb++; ktb++;
    } 
    read_untilGE_(b, a);
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: "I really like recursion because it's how we think" -- who is this "we" that you're referring to?  If you think this is how the entire human race thinks, or even the subset of all programmers, I'd submit that you're quite wrong.  For me, some problems are naturally recursive and some are not.

Comment: I didn't expect the Spanish Inquisition! Hence I didn't give enough thought to that statement. I was just overjoyed that I'd figured out how to get my results by applying recursion and went too far. I was really trying to say "recursion is how I imagine a lot of programmers would think about solving this particular problem" and not just a few others. More specifically, a non-Java programmer (i.e., without using the FileVisitor interface) would find that recursion makes it relatively simple to walk the Windows file tree. I'd like to see a non-recursive solution to either that or my problem.

Comment: BRING OUT THE COMFY CHAIR ...

Comment: Our chief weapon is surprise...surprise and fear...fear and surprise.... our two weapons are fear and surprise...and ruthless efficiency.... Our three weapons are fear, surprise, and ruthless efficiency...and an almost fanatical devotion to the Pope.... Our four...no... amongst our weapons.... amongst our weaponry...are such elements as fear, surprise.... I'll come in again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got off to the right start by passing your two `Scanner`s as parameters to your method, so that you call your method recursively by switching the parameters.  Then you erred by using a `Scanner` (`sca`) that wasn't one of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @ajb. I wish I'd've seen it myself; it's pretty obvious, now that you've pointed it out! I implemented a change that is consistent with your observation and got no errors, and program ended with EOF, but it was only about 90% accurate, so I have more work to do, but maybe your hint will get me what I need--tomorrow. I'm dead tired.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ajb's quick response and a good night's (... well, a few hours') sleep, I got exactly what I wanted. The fix wasn't quite as simple as changing `Scanner` `sca` to `a`, but it was exactly the problem that I failed to notice.

**And I failed to notice it because of sloppy coding. I had too many global variables, especially `sca` and `scb`. Had they been local to `main`, I'd've caught the problem last night.**

Here's the method that calls itself. The '--------------------' lines are the changes relative to the error in logic that ajb pointed out.

```
  private static int read_untilGE_(Scanner a, String sa, long ma, 
                                   Scanner b, String sb, long mb){
    String indent;
    boolean shouldPrint;
    if (ma == mapa){indent = inda; shouldPrint = showa;}
    else           {indent = indb; shouldPrint = showb;}

    if(shouldPrint) System.out.println(indent + sa); // --------------------

    while(a.hasNext()){                              // --------------------

      sa = a.next();                                 // --------------------

      if(sa.equals(sb))        return 0;  // a = b
      if(sa.compareTo(sb) > 0) break;     // a > b
      if(shouldPrint) System.out.println(indent + sa); 
    } 
    read_untilGE_(b, sb, mb, a, sa, ma);
    return 0;
  }
```

And here's the rest of the program:

```
package filecomparison;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryCompare {

  static  long     mapa, mapb;
  static  String   inda, indb;
  static  Boolean  showa = true,  showb = true;

  private static void drain(String msg, Scanner sc){
    int k = 0;
    System.out.println("\n\nDraining " + msg);
    String s;
      while(sc.hasNext()){
        s = sc.next();
        System.out.println(s);
        ++k;
      }
      System.out.println("\nExtras at end: " + k);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner  sca,                  scb;
    String   reca,                 recb;

    Path a = Paths.get("C:\\newdic.txt");
    Path b = Paths.get("C:\\WordHelp.dick");

    sca = new Scanner(a);   scb = new Scanner(b);    
    mapa = a.hashCode(  );  mapb = b.hashCode();
    inda = "";              indb = "\t\t\t";

    System.out.println("Extra words in:\n" + inda + " " + a + "\n" + indb + b );

    while(sca.hasNext() && scb.hasNext()){

        reca = sca.next(); 
        recb = scb.next(); 

        int compareResult = reca.compareTo(recb);

        if(     compareResult < 0) read_untilGE_(sca, reca, mapa, scb, recb, mapb);  // a < b
        else if(compareResult > 0) read_untilGE_(scb, recb, mapb, sca, reca, mapa);  // a > b
                                                                     // recursion makes a = b at this point        
    }
    if(sca.hasNext())drain(a.toFile().toString(), sca);    
    if(scb.hasNext())drain(b.toFile().toString(), scb);
    sca.close();          scb.close();
  } // end main
}
```

Comment: Let me add that I greatly appreciate @ajb **merely giving a hint** and **not** writing the method FOR ME, as I had asked.